# What is the significance of Lily Luna Potter's middle name?

Tags: harry-potter, names

All of Harry's other children have middle names that honour people who played a serious part not just in his life, but in the second wizarding war: James *Sirius* Potter, and Albus *Severus* Potter.

Whereas Lily *Luna* Potter takes her middle name from someone in his generation, in fact someone who is, to my knowledge still alive.

Is this an anomaly or something deliberate by JKR, who is known for putting a lot of thought into her characters' names? Without hating on Luna, she doesn't seem to contribute as much as any of the other names givers.

Comment: Not enough girls in his dad's generation?

Comment: Minerva, Molly, Nyphadora....

Comment: Isn't luna the name of the girl that keeps on losing her possessions in 'the Order of the Phoenix' I suppose ?

Comment: Maybe he finally let his wife pick a name for one of their children?

Comment: @Pureferret: Generation before his father's, alive, generation after his father's.

Comment: @dlanod Dumbledore definitely wasn't the same generation as the others, so I don't think it's generational by any means. As for Nymphadora, she could well be the same generation as James, etc, despite being younger.

Comment: I think the point I grasping at is that, at some point, Albus, Severus, James, Sirius and Lily were in the Order of the Phoenix. Luna was part of DA, but I don't know if she fully joined TootP

Comment: I doubt that she did, but that doesn't mean she wasn't important. Also, as I alluded to in my other comment, all of the other names are people who were important specifically to Harry; his father, his godfather, his mother, Dumbledore, Snape. Luna was one of Ginny's better friends at school, and one of the only students who was always willing to help and support Harry, so I don't see why they *wouldn't* use her name. Also, it allows for alliteration, which JKR seems to really love when choosing names.

Comment: I did not realise that Luna was a close friend of Ginny's. That's answer-worthy.

Comment: Don't forget Ginny has a say in the names too. And naming your kid after someone many people think you should have married instead of your wife is going to be a very bad marriage enrichment strategy.

Comment: Because "Lily Nymphadora Potter" just doesn't flow off the tongue.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

There are several areas where Luna stood out in Harry's mind:

1. She was the first person he knew who could also see the Thestrals
2. She was a member of Dumbledore's Army
3. She went with Harry and company to the Ministry of Magic at the end of Order of the Phoenix
4. She was held captive by the Death Eaters as leverage over her father

I think that she gave as much to the cause as many of the adult members of the Order of the Phoenix. The fact that Ginny liked her would have made it easy to honor her.

Comment: She was also supporting Harry (over her own house) in Quidditch

Comment: Don't forget the painting Harry has seen in Luna's bedroom.

Comment: She also believed in Harry when he wasn't sure if he believed in himself. From experience, that can really mean a lot to someone.

Comment: Luna always helped Harry when he was out of allies, I agree with Gabe that it means *a lot*. And without the Lovegoods they wouldn't find enough information on the Deathly Hallows, so they were actually crucial. They also released supporting articles about him in the newspaper, when in the greatest need for it.

Comment: @b_jonas that painting still gives me goosebumps just thinking about it.

Comment: Personally, I always thought Luna would have been Harry's correct love interest if Rowling hadn't been so determined to put him and Ginny together.  She and Harry had a more developed relationship than him and Ginny, and frankly, she was a more interesting character.

Comment: @naxa Speaking of "out of allies", I believe she and Neville were the only DA members to respond to the coin Hermione made

Comment: She was also his friend...

Comment: Luna was also instrumental in leading Harry to the last horcrux. It's possible that without her help he never would have found it.

Answer (score 12):

I believe that I once heard JKR also said that Luna was her attempt to place herself in the novels.   I also thought that Lily included Luna's name to continue the homage to the author herself.

I went searching for the original source where I got this idea.   I haven't found it yet, but I did find this from Muggle Net:  http://www.mugglenet.com/jkrinterview2.shtml

> MA: You said that during the writing of Book 6 something caused you fiendish glee. Do you remember what that was?
>
> JKR: Oh, god. [Long silence as Jo thinks] What was it? It wasn't really vindictive [laughter] - that was more of a figure of speech. I know what I've enjoyed writing - you know Luna's commentary during the Quidditch match? [Laughter] It was that. I really enjoyed doing that. Actually I really enjoyed doing that.
> You know, that was the last Quidditch match. I knew as I wrote it that it was the last time I was going to be doing a Quidditch match. To be honest with you, Quidditch matches have been the bane of my life in the Harry Potter books. They are necessary in that people expect Harry to play Quidditch, but there is a limit to how many ways you can have them play Quidditch together and for something new to happen.
> And then I had this moment of blinding inspiration. I thought, Luna's going to commentate, and that was just a gift. **It's the kind of commentary I'd do on a sports match because I'm** -[laughs]. Anyway yeah, it was that.

I may be wrong, but I can almost hear her completing that last sentence as "because I am Luna".

Comment: I think it's also alluded to in the list of character names on pottermore, but I'm not certain.

Comment: But JKR's said a million times that she's Hermione. :/

Comment: She could just as easily been about to say "I'm not a sports fan" or even "I'm not a fan of sports commentary." Nothing sucks the fun out of a game more than so-called experts talking about it.

Answer (score 7):

Harry's youngest and oldest kids are named after the Mauraders in some was. Luna was a good friend of Ginny's , and Moony was Lupin's nickname s. moony. Luna means "moon" in Latin.

Answer (score 2):

She was named after important people in her father's life. Lily - after his mother and her parental grandmother, Lily Evans, who died to protect Harry from Voldemort when he was just a baby. 
Luna - after two people; Luna Lovegood, a good and old family friend that both Harry and Ginny had turned to for comfort in times of need, but also after Remus LupinHe was the last Marauder to die and was a werewolf, therefore affected by the moon; Luna means moon and Lupin's nickname was Moony
-wiki

Comment: Do you have canon backup for "Lupin" statement? If not, then the rest of the answer simply duplicates what other answers stated.

Answer (score 2):

### The significance of her middle name is never stated in the epilogue.

It's never even stated that her middle name is actually in honor of Luna Lovegood. It's a fair assumption that it is, though, since she is the only Luna mentioned so far. In addition, the epilogue is the end of the Harry Potter series. There would be no reason to write in another Luna who we've never seen before, and if Lily was meant to have a middle name not related to anyone we know, she would have been given a name that wasn't shared by anyone who played a significant part in the story.

However, though Luna was a good friend to both Harry and Ginny, she seems like an odd choice to name one of their children after. She did also contribute to the war, and I'm not suggesting that she's unimportant or didn't have a meaningful role in Harry's life.

But Harry can't possibly name a child after everyone who's meant something to him. There are far too many people who have helped him for that to be possible. He'd have to either have a ridiculously large number of children or give them all Dumbledore-style long names to honor everyone who deserves it. There's Arthur Weasley, Neville Longbottom, Mad-Eye Moody, Professor McGonagall, Tonks, Cedric, Kingsley Shacklebolt, and presuming that we don't put any criteria other than "were important positive figures in either Harry's or Ginny's lives", the list goes on. It would make sense for them to, either consciously or not, limit the list of name choices somehow.

Considering the fact that Harry and Ginny would have to choose carefully who they honor with a name, Luna is an odd choice. She was their classmate, and is presumably still alive at the time they named their daughter. Unless they grew apart over the years, they also probably still see Luna and have contact with her. Something similar could be said about Neville. He was a significant presence in both Harry's and Ginny's lives, and performed heroic acts during the war. However, none of the Potter children have a name related to Neville. Which is understandable - the epilogue shows that the Potter family has remained close with him, and he is living a happy life as the Herbology professor at Hogwarts. Both Harry and Ginny liked Luna, so it seems likely that they would have kept up some level of friendship with her - and if for some reason they didn't and had a falling out with them, they probably wouldn't want to name their child after her.

The big thing that the names of Harry's children have in common, other than being people who have meant the most to him, is that their namesakes are all *dead*, and died in a tragic way as a result of the wizarding war. This is most likely because Harry wanted to honor those who had died in the war, and who gave their lives to help him win it. It's also a way to manage the list of choices somehow. In addition, it's more practical to name children after a dead person than a living one. Having two living people with the same name could be confusing, especially if Harry has stayed in close contact with the original owner of the name - which if he respected them enough to name a child after, he likely would.

**The best theory I've heard is that it's also in honor of Lupin, but this is not proven.**

Harry's first son, James Sirius, was named after his father and his godfather. Harry's second son, Albus Severus, was named after his mentor who was dead and the teacher who suffered and ultimately sacrificed his own life for Harry. Lily is the youngest Potter child, and her first name is in honor of Harry's mother.

Maybe Harry also wanted to honor Lupin with his child's name, but since she was a girl, he couldn't exactly name her Lily Remus, because Remus is obviously a boy's name. There's also no feminine form of either Remus or Lupin. So if he wanted Lily's name to be in honor of him, he'd have to be a bit more creative.

Luna sounds like Lupin, and means moon. Lupin was a werewolf whose transformations were caused by the full moon, and Lupin's Marauder nickname was Moony. Both he and Ginny would have positive associations with the name due to Luna Lovegood, since they were both good friends with her. Those might not be enough to convince them to name their child after Luna alone, but it might help contribute to them choosing the name in honor of Lupin.

Comment: I mean the female form of Lupin is [Lupa](http://phelous.com/category/obscurus-lupa/).

Comment: Rowling said on Twitter that Harry didn't name any children after Lupin.

Comment: *The significance of her middle name is never stated in the epilogue.* Her middle name itself is never even stated in the epilogue.

Answer (score 2):

This is mostly speculation of a fan, but... perhaps it was much for the same reasons he named Albus after Dumblebore and Snape; not only was he honoring people he saw as heroic, but he wanted Lily to embody some of the qualities Luna had. Also.. Luna was a good, if odd friend to Harry.

Think about it. Over the course of 3 books, Luna and Harry shared almost as much as Harry and Neville had in the series:

- Their first meeting in year 5 was odd, but cute, as they were both being somewhat victimized (Harry for saying Voldemort was alive, Luna for her eccentricities). This "shared hardship"... a condition which has been shown to deepen intimacy between individuals.... was further cemented  by the fact that among the Hogwarts students, only *they* in that year could see the thestrals.
- Luna's were the first words of true comfort Harry had at this point. When Ron and Hermione could offer him little peace due to his trauma the previous year, the worsening situation with Voldemort, and the victimization at the hands of the Ministry and Umbridge, this girl with her *own* issues took time out to treat him warmly. Luna was the first person *not* connected to Harry to say she believes him about Voldemort, as well as to offer him a (very small) bright side, or at least a slightly comforting perspective, to his situation.
- It was Luna who helped them get to the Ministry of Magic (since the others couldn't see thestrals, they'd never have thought of using them.)
- Luna was the one who found him after Malfoy left him on the train (in the film), even ended up fixing his nose.
- It was Luna he ended up taking to the Professor's dinner party.
- The situation with her father and the Death-Eaters while they were on the run in book 7 would likely have served to bring them closer.
- It was *Luna* who helps him enter the Ravenclaw common room to find the 5th horcrux, and she actively participated in the Battle of Hogwarts protecting the others.

In other words, Luna proved herself to be brave, loyal, compassionate, dependable and a true friend, if a little "out there." All of these are qualities I'm sure Harry would have wanted his daughter to have, as well as being an affectionate reminder of his well-meaning school chum. the fact that Luna could *also* reference one of his favorite Professors and extended family members in Lupin I'm sure didn't  hurt the fact, if not outright occurring to Harry and Ginny as a way to honor two people they cared about dearly.

Answer (score -3):

It is very simple guys. Don't forget Luna was the one because of whom Harry found one of the seven horcruxes, that is the tiara. If it wasn't for her Harry couldn't have won the war anyway0. Also, Harry named his children after very important people in his life and Luna is the only one to be alive right now. She is one of Harry's closest friends and had taught Harry so much. Like how to embrace your differences. It would make a lot of sense for Harry to have named her after Luna.

Answer (score -3):

Although I don't think that Harry named his daughter after Lupin. There is no proof from JK Rowling herself, and she owns this wonderful world. Harry had all of his friends' memories preserved, whether they were alive or dead. Luna's memory (even though she is still alive and in touch with Harry) is his daughter, which is shared by Harry's mother, Lily. Lupin and Tonks' memory is still alive because Harry is their son's godfather. There is no proof that Lily Luna Potter was also named after Lupin.